# Dreamweaver CS5 crash when I open certain files

Tags: dreamweaver

I've been using CS4 for over a year without problems. Today I installed Dreamweaver CS5 and, well... I have not been able to do my work because it keeps crashing. When i try to open certain files (in this case: index.php) it crashes.

I also had a problem with the "upload on save" option untill I unchecked the "Use alternative FTP move method" option in the server settings.

I've tried googling for this problem without luck. Does anyone know a solution for this?

**UPDATE:**

After testing every line of code in index.php I finally found the source of the problem. If I add this line to the file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Reenie+Beanie">
```

Dreamweaver CS5 stops working. Could someone with CS5 installed try it?

Comment: Tried on Windows 7 and Vista and no crash in CS5 when I open a file with that code snippet in the page. Perhaps it is some other code, or in combination with that code.

Answer (score 4):

It's definitely the external links that are the issue.  The culprit in my case was a font file also being loaded from Google.

**Problem:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Reenie+Beanie">
```

Commenting or removing this line does work, but the problem is that I need this font to test the website as I'm developing.  What I did instead (since I'm using PHP) was echo out the link so that DW can't try to crawl it.

**Solution:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Reenie+Beanie"; ?>">
```

It's pointless code, but it works - DW will stop hanging and the font will still work when testing in a live environment.

Comment: Thanks for this --- solved it for me. This issue's been driving me mad with DW pre-loading something from external font urls.

Comment: No problem - glad it helped.  I've experienced the same issue trying to load external JS scripts and even images.  The method of using PHP or some server side code to write out the URL seems to work in all cases.  DW won't try to do whatever it's doing and crash.

Answer (score 3):

Dreamweaver CS5 definitely has issues with externally sourced items.  I just got the same type of failure when trying to include jquery from googleapi:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Removing the line or commenting it out allows Dreamweaver to open and work with the file.

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with files reaching exactly a file size around 8KB and then Dreamweaver would crash until you went in and adding or removing a character from the file using a different text editor.  It happened to me a few times hand coding and saving files.

You may also try saving that font as reenie-beanie.css locally to the site so you get something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="media/styles/reenieBeanie.css" />
```

It's possible that a firewall or something is scaring DW when it reaches out for that file live in the preview or split screen mode.

Answer (score 0):

Great, this post helped me solve my problems of crashed on a specific file in Dreamweaver CS5.
It's indeed the external font that crashes DW.

I found an easy fix, omit the protocol part and it works:

```
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

and **NOT**

```
<link href="http//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 0):

**FIX FOR ME IN LOCAL CSS FILE:** I had to right click on each file and try to "Edit with Dreamweaver" until I found the one that really was behind the crashing on start up. I got the crash on index and a specifc css file (local).

I;m using Bootstrap 3. Works fine on my laptop running wamp, but not on my main PC using IIS7. I tried all the other registry cleaning and cache cleaning techniques, but no go until I removed this one piece of code from the local css file.

Hope it helps someone else.

This I removed this section of a css file:

```
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { 
    .featured-box{
        margin-top:5px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this from a long time ago but it maybe helpful for others. This is what solved the crashing problem with Dreamweaver CS6 and bootstrap files for my computer. Dreamweaver crashes every time I linked to a bootstrap file. I changed my computer to have a lower screen resolution, for example to 1280x768. I restarted Dreamweaver and bootstrap doesn't crash my Dreamweaver anymore. The strange thing is when I tried this on my husband's 17" LG Gram laptop, this solution doesn't work. I'm not sure what the right combination is (resolution, hardware etc.), to make it work on one computer vs another.

Answer (score -1):

First I put the comment tag around the jQuery link to see that it was as suggested above and no it was not.

The problem started after I started the media query in the CSS. I left it fragmented [I had not finished]

Here is the fragment with comment tags around it to disable it.

```
    /*
@media screen and (max-width:
*/
```

The comment tags for html are different than the css ones they look like this:  `<!--  [line of html code] -->`

For css use:   `/*   [line of CSS code]  */`

Using the comment tags to disable suspect code is more handy than  just deleting things.

Hope that helps somone/
-mack318